# Check if a string contains a token from a list, with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to check if a string `s` contains any of the tokens in the list `L`.

Is there a built-in function in Javascript for this? or do I have to do it manually with something like:

```
function present(s, L) {
  for (var i = 0; i < L.length; i++)
    if (s.indexOf(L[i]) !== -1)
      return true;
  return false;
}

var L = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
var s = 'Yes, definitely.';
present(s, L);  // true
```

Comment: try using the array.filter

Comment: Can you provide an example, for future reference @GopalkrishnaNarayanPrabhu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify your loop with the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) higher-order function, and use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) instead of `indexOf`:

```
L.some(token => s.includes(token))
```

Comment: Impressive! Does this syntax work on all browsers? It looks like magic (I don't remember since when is `=>` supported).

Comment: @Basj http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions, for `some` and `includes` see the compatibility tables at MDN

Comment: For wider support, we could use `L.some(function(t) { return s.includes(t)});`.

Comment: @Basj However `includes` requires ES6 anyway, so we'd need the polyfill for that to make it work in IE

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a Regular Expression with all the items in `list` by sticking a `|` operator between each of them. Then use [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to check for a match:

```
function isPresent(string, list) {
    return new RegExp(list.join('|')).test(string)
}
var list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
var string = 'Yes, definitely.';
isPresent(string, list);  // true
```

Comment: You need to be certain that none of the tokens contain special characters though, or you'd need to escape them.

Comment: @Bergi very true! Good catch.